# write a buffer in memory from C/C++ and read from it in java without JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, buffer

I have a question, is this possible and how? Reading bytes from a buffer in the memory that has been created from C/C++ with Java? My idea is to use JNI for starting a cycle in C++ that writes bytes in a buffer and only send the direction of the buffer to Java, then Java reads the bytes from it in another cycle. The goal is to reduce the call of JNI functions, because I noticed that they reduce the performance. I want to know which classes I must use in Java and what functions in C++.

In advance thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a ByteBuffer. The simplest approach is to use a `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` using the address allocated by Java.  If you have to use the address provided by C, you can change the address and limit (for the size) to point to anywhere you like.

If you would rather use something more low level, on the Oracle JVM you can use the `Unsafe.getXxxx(long address)` or `Unsafe.setXxxx(long address, T value)` methods, but these must be used with care as incorrect usage can crash the JVM. (Just like using an invalid pointer would in C)  These methods are used by ByteBuffer and are turned into a single machine code instruction which optimised.

Comment: then i can use java for allocate an address in the memory and use it in C for write in that buffer? i thank you for you answer

Comment: You can.  This is the safest approach. You may want to set the byte order as the default is big endian (but on x86/x64 its little endian in C) Use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())` and it will be correct on any platform.